# Move canvas line up and down based on variable value on the page load with smooth transistion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on canvas I have created Vertical line, horizontal line What exactly I want move my horizontal line based on variable value till the height of vertical line. So for that I have created one function call move() in this function i have variable call linemove. If my value was 0 the horizontal line should be in the bottom of the vertical line again If i enter the value of 20 in that variable it has to move smoothly towards up. So If i gave 100 it has to move to top of the horizontal li I don't no how to apply variable for the vertical canvas

Here is my javascript function I have started

```
function move()
{
 var linemove = 0;
}
```

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8WcTe/)

Thanks in advance
Maha

Answer (score 0):

First off, try not reusing variable names if you are going to need them later. A solution to your problem is that you can add a parameter to your function and do away with your variable. Then what you actually want to accomplish is to clear the previous line and draw the line in a different position. I have edited your code here:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(220, 200);
context.lineTo(220, 20);
context.stroke();

var canvas1 = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
context1.beginPath();
context1.moveTo(20, 20);
context1.lineTo(80, 20);
context1.stroke();


function move(y)
{
    context1.clearRect(0,0,canvas1.width,canvas1.height);
    context1.beginPath();
    context1.moveTo(20, y);
    context1.lineTo(80, y);
    context1.stroke();
}
```

You simply need to call move(y) with whatever height you want.

Comment: hi the above code was not working i tried added some value in that y but still not working

Comment: You are not supposed to replace the y. You need to call the function like this move(Whatever height you want). Make sure that the value that you insert is less than the height of the canvas. Take a look at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/fizzsim/8WcTe/1/ The move(150) function moves your line to y=150.